# TOleServer in delphi ... Equivalent .NET Class?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have some delphi code which I need to migrate / port / re-write to .NET

The code uses TOleServer. Could you please let me know any .NET equivalent implementation of this particular class.

Is it available via unmanaged code?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COM servers are available in .NET through [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bw51z5z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You didn't mention how your Delphi code uses `TOleServer`. If it implements its own COM server then you have the following options:

- Keep it as it is and simply reference it from your .NET code, or
- Port it to .NET as a class and, if needed, expose it to COM

If your Delphi code uses `TOleServer` to reference an external COM server, you can simply do the same from .NET.

Comment: TOndrej, just one question out of curiosity.. I am a C# programmer. I now have a Delphi project which I need to convert it into .NET, I really need some advice on how to proceed... Should I learn how to code in Delphi and then proceed with migration or should I use an automated tool which churns out C# code (using Delphi Pascal code)... I would love to learn delphi but i am running short of time.. Pls advice. (By the way. This project communicates to a COM server.. )

Comment: From your comment I assume your Delphi code is **using** an external COM server, not **implementing** one. Then this COM client code is what you need to port from native Delphi to .NET. If you're running short of time probably your best option is to hire someone who knows both Delphi and C#/.NET to do it for you. On the other hand, well-written, good-style Delphi code is usually easy to understand. Also, depending on the code, rebuilding in [Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/prism) (Delphi for .NET) might be worth giving a try. Good luck!

Comment: I am new to COM as well.. but I would love to learn stuffs, let me see.. I am going to give it a try... loads of thanks.. will keep you posted. I surely would have some queries in future.

Comment: IEnumObj = interface(IUnknown) ['{0000-0q394039-93849}'] function RemoteNext(a:LongWord; out b:IUnknown; out c:LongWord):HResult; stdcall; end;